# What are elements of a field called

Tags: linear-algebra

From [Linear Algebra by Serge Lang](http://books.google.com/books?id=0DUXym7QWfYC&hl=en) we have

> "Let K be a field. Elements of K will also be called
>   **numbers** (without specification) if the reference to K is made clear by the context, or they will be called **scalars**."

What is the meaning of "if the reference to K is made clear by the context"? Is in this context the term numbers equivalent to scalars? Are there any difference between numbers and scalars in general?

Comment: Beats me. Maybe the term "scalar" emphasizes that there is a vector space in the conversation too, since vectors are "scaled".

Comment: It's possible he is saying something like "sometimes I will refer to these things as _numbers_ and sometimes I will refer to them as _scalars_, and I can't be bothered to make sure I am consistent. If I use either of these terms without explicitly mentioning a field $K$, you should be able to deduce what $K$ is from context."

Comment: The first chapter, where the definition is, is about vector spaces. In many situations in algebra, the vector space has some field/ring structure, which might be ignored in that situation. It would be wrong to say "Let $x$ be a number" then.

Comment: In my opinion, this is very sloppy talk. Please remember, this book was written by The Great Serge Lang, but he was still an ordinary fallible human being, not an infallible deity. There are situations where the constant-field (“scalar-field”) of a vector space does not consist of numbers at all. The moral? Don’t spend any more time worrying about the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Scalar* is used to differentiate them from *vector*.

Vector spaces come with two operations: *vector addition* $u+v$ and *scalar multiplication* $\lambda v$.

So, *scalar* is used when a number *scales* a vector (hence the name).

Comment: Why would _number_ not be just as good at accomplishing this?

Comment: @alex.jordan Consider $K$ subfield of $L$. Then $L$ is a vector field over $K$.. Which are the numbers?

Comment: Is it that if $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is being viewed as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$, that elements of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are the "numbers"?

Comment: @alex.jordan By definition "number" means an element in the field... But both are fields... So is a number in that situation a vector or a scalar? Note, that the issue appears when you start saying: Let $x$ be a number.... And even worse, what if you look at $\mathbb Q$ as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$? Yes, I know it is trivial but still....

Answer (score 1):

In Linear Algebra, we can sometimes use vector spaces whose elements "look" just like scalars.  For example:

> Define the vector space $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$ with:
>
> - Addition: $x+y = xy$
> - Scalar multiplication: $rx = x^r$

Clearly, we could call $x$, $y$, and $r$ "numbers."  Yet, in this context, it is unclear which numbers are *vectors* and which are *scalars*.  So, we call $x$ and $y$ **vectors** and $r$ a **scalar**.  This is what is meant by "when it cannot be determined by context."